# Trying to login using oauth. Can someone explain the documentation how to get access token?

Tags: jira-rest-api

I understand that I need to call:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://auth.atlassian.com/oauth/token' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"grant_type": "authorization_code","client_id": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID","client_secret": "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET","code": "YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_CODE","redirect_uri": "https://YOUR_APP_CALLBACK_URL"}'
```

to get access token. There is some attempt to explain what are `client_id, client_secret, code, redirect_uri`, but it's totally cryptic to me. Can someone explain to me, what these are and where to get them?

I can login to company jira. I can create my personal access token in my profile. I cant get any meaningful support from my company. I need to get somehow from here to access token, so that I can call rest api.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth needs that the user login through a web interface.
Once logged, is possible to retrieve the `code` you are looking for in the URL.

In my case, in order to get that code I have to open the oauth login web page of the service I want to use (in your case atlassian) and just login.

I usually manage this process with code, not using curls.

`redirect_uri` is where you want to be redirected after you login in the web interface.
i.e. Do I need to login with atlassian in order to call api and use data from my app ?

- mobile app/Desktop App (redirect_uri will be a schema defined by you in the app, could be something like: `myCompany://myApplicationExample` or with desktop `http://localhost` should work ). In this case I suggest you to read something about deeplink for applications.
- website (redirect_uri will the url of your website : `https://yourwebsite.com`

In my case, with the services I usually work with, `cliend_id` and `client_secret` are given per user or per application, when requested to the company which provides services you need.

I hope this can help you clarify

BY THE WAY:
if you say you already have an Access Token , you should be able to do everything without Loggin in, because the final purpose of login and use all this parameters you asked for, is to get an Access Token.
The endpoint you are trying to call, will just return you an Access Token.
The Access token is what you need in order to call rest api in this case.

I would suggest you to try to call an atlassian rest API you want, using the Access Token you already have in the headers of the rest API, and see the results.

In my case, I have to create an header like this:

Authorization : Bearer {your Access token}

I hope this helps you.

EDIT:

As shown in point 1 in this doc https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/oauth-2-3lo-apps/

you should open this url by your application:

```
https://auth.atlassian.com/authorize?
  audience=api.atlassian.com&
  client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&
  scope=REQUESTED_SCOPE_ONE%20REQUESTED_SCOPE_TWO&
  redirect_uri=https://YOUR_APP_CALLBACK_URL&
  state=YOUR_USER_BOUND_VALUE&
  response_type=code&
  prompt=consent
```

read the doc on you should set redirect_uri (http://localhost is valid if is a desktop application, but you will have to implement an http listener in order to get the authorization code, I suggest you to set a schema in you app or simply use a web page url).
You should get a client_id by atlassian to use in the url,same for scope.
I don't know exaclty the state parameter but in the docs should be writtend.
Once logged you will be redirected to the redirect_uri you set, getting also this authorization_code, then you can call the /token endpoint in order to get the Access Token.

```
curl --request POST \
```

--url 'https://auth.atlassian.com/oauth/token' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--data '{"grant_type": "authorization_code","client_id": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID","client_secret": "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET","code": "YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_CODE","redirect_uri": "https://YOUR_APP_CALLBACK_URL"}'

Here you have to use the authorization code you get from the login, re use the same client_id, set also the client_secret (should be given with the client_id) and re use the same redirect_uri you used in the login url.

Once done you will have finally the Access Token, which must be used in order to call Apis.

as shown in the doc you should be able to call apis like this curl

```
curl --request GET \
```

--url https://api.atlassian.com/oauth/token/accessible-resources 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' 
--header 'Accept: application/json'

Where 'ACCESS_TOKEN' will be your access token obtained before.
Remind that an Access Token usually has an expiration date, after which you will need to login again or refreshing the token.

EDIT 2:

A Client ID is an identifier associated with an application that assists with client / server OAuth 2.0 authentication.

So basically is a constant string, this should be given to you from atlassian/jira in some way.

Client Secret should be given to you with Client ID from atlassian/jira.

Client_id and client_secret usually are also called api keys.

Usually the Scope is the name of the application you are requesting api keys for (you should request new api keys for each application),this is up to you, and should be comunicated to the company in your case (atlassian/jira) when requesting api keys.

(i.e. For my company I work with Trimble Connect, which is just a platform, everytime I develop for example a plugin/addon on top of it  I ask them new api keys)

for what concerns the state:
*state: (required for security) Set this to a value that is associated with the user you are directing to the authorization URL, for example, a hash of the user's session ID. Make sure that this is a value that cannot be guessed. You may be able to generate and validate this value automatically, if you are using an OAuth 2.0 client library or an authentication library with OAuth 2.0 support.*

In the beginning I would try to give the state a random value.

I think you should ask to Atlassian how to get your api keys (maybe there's a page for that, like for Trimble Connect in my case).
I would send them an e-mail.

Seems you are not interested in call Apis from an application you are developing, but just from curls.
if I'm right, I know I have already told you, but if I were you I would definitely try to call an atlassian API not trying to get the access token from the OAuth Login, but using that ACCESS TOKEN you told me you told me you manually created.

Please try this curl:

```
curl --request GET \
```

--url https://api.atlassian.com/oauth/token/accessible-resources 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}' 
--header 'Accept: application/json'

just use your Access Token string instead of {ACCESS_TOKEN} and see the results.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but tbh, I cannot follow it. When I log in to our company jira, there is nothing in url to take and use as access token. And I don't yet have access token obtained from authentication, I have only personal access token, which cannot be used like that (maybe it's blocked by admin? I don't know).  Trying 'bearer' header as you shown, produces the same result as sending basic: Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. I tried to send it as is, and also as email:token as base64. Neither works.

Comment: You don’t get the access token in the url, you get the authorization code, then you have to use this code with all other parameters you asked for in order to call the ”/token” endpoint and retrieve the access token in the payload of the response.

Comment: In my URL there is no code. I didnt see any of what is in docs anywhere. I apologize for not being able to understand what you suggest. Can you share curl(ideally), screenshots, code samples or anything which contains full info? I TOTALLY miss how this should work. In their attlassian docs they show I need to pass A, B and C, without actually showing anywhere what that is or where to get it.

Comment: Can you please show me the documentation you are talking about? I will try to help you

Comment: THANKS! For example this: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/oauth-2-3lo-apps/ Not sure if this is correct one, it just seems to be the most relevant one. But I saw 10+ different pages on authorization, I have no idea what is correct one, and I don't know how to find correct one. My situation is:I don't have admin jira privileges,but I can login, and create personal access token. Theoretically I can try to ask local admin (if I find him) for something, but so far I don't even know what.So this is my starting point.Please suggest what to try/find-out/ask for to be able to login

Comment: I edited my answer, trying to explain you a bit more in the details how to follow the doc, if you need clarifications let me know

Comment: I apologise, I cannot follow. Doing anything technical, like listening for callback, is not a problem. Doing the first call is problem: what is client_id, what is scope, what is state? What shall I sent there? Can you elaborate? I read dozen of pages but still cannot do single step... Client&scope are some constant from installation or licensing or ...? (yes, all if this should be somewhere in docs, but even after fer hours of search I didnt find it)

Comment: I Edited my answer with some more detail, let me know if it is clear or not :)

Comment: Thanks for reply, will try that out. But I figured out, that our admins are 'a little bit' behind, so what is stated in 2019 docs as deprecated and insecure still works, so I can use that momentarily. I'll try to ask admins for client/admin keys, we will see how that will go.

Comment: Perfect, just remember that if you are going to create an application which needs to use 3rd party services, the oAuth is the way to go.